# .includes Not Finding Period

Tags: javascript, forms, function

I have a JavaScript function that prevents a user from typing any character but numbers and a period. I also am trying to prevent a user from typing multiple periods. From my observations of how this script is working, if a user types a period and then a number (".1"), they won't be able to type anymore periods after nor before that until the first one is removed. Yet for some reason the user can type two or more consecutive periods ("..") without the function preventing it. Interestingly, that causes the function to not find any decimals and thus allows the user to type as many decimals as their heart desires. Here is the code I am working with:

```js
function isNumberKey(evt){
 if (evt.keyCode == 0) {
  var charCode = evt.charCode;
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode != 46 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))) {
   return false;
  } else {
   if (charCode == 46) {
    if (document.getElementById('inputBox').value.includes(".") == true) {
     return false;
    } else {
     return true;
    }
   } else {
    return true;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<form name="form" id="form" onsubmit="calculate(); return false;" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <input type="number" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" value="0" min="0" id="inputBox">
</form>
```

Feel free to play with it. Maybe I am not using the right thing to find the period. What am I doing wrong here? Why is it allowing a period to be typed right after another period is already present?

I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but I am on the latest Firefox on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you declared this `input` as `number`, so '.' are being removed from its value. Just change input type to `text`:

```js
function isNumberKey(evt){
 if (evt.keyCode == 0) {
  var charCode = evt.charCode;
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode != 46 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))) {
   return false;
  } else {
   if (charCode == 46) {
    if (document.getElementById('inputBox').value.includes(".") == true) {
     return false;
    } else {
     return true;
    }
   } else {
    return true;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<form name="form" id="form" onsubmit="calculate(); return false;" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <input type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" value="0" min="0" id="inputBox">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your entire `isNumberKey` function is included inside an `if` statement that checks if the event's `keyCode` is zero. When you type a period, the `keyCode` is `46`. So your logic never gets executed.

As a side not, `KeyboardEvent.keyCode` is deprecated; you shouldn't use it. MDN recommends using `KeyboardEvent.key` instead.

As guijob said, you should also change the input's `type` to `text`.

Comment: The if statement is the content of the function. It itself is not inside an if statement. The if statement is the logic. I tested the `keyCode` output with `console.log()` and I chose to use it because it works. When I write the output of `KeyboardEvent` to the console, the value of `charCode` is `46` but the value of `keyCode` is `0` for a period. It is `0` for any letter but not for other keys such as `Tab`, `Home`, or `End`. I added that check to prevent other bugs related to those other keys.